# Pivot an array of array?

Tags: powershell

The following code defined a matrix.

```
$a = @('a','b','x',10), 
     @('a','b','y',20), 
     @('c','e','x',50), 
     @('c','e','y',30)

$a | % { "[$_]"}
```

I want to pivot the array by `x` and `y`. The expected result array should be

```
[a b 10 20]
[c e 50 30]
 - - -- --
     x  y
```

I think it needs `group-object` and then mapping. How to use `group-object` on an array?

(BTW, why the question has been down voted twice?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Group-Object` with an array (at least not the way you want) since Group-Object works on object properties. A workaround is to organize your rows into a label that you want to group on, followed by the values to assign to the group. Then you can group on the label:

```
$a | %{ 
    new-object PsObject -prop @{"label" = "$($_[0]),$($_[1])"; value=@{ $_[2]=$_[3]}} 
} | Group-Object label
```

So, then you have a group with your entries stroed as an array of hashtables within each group:

```
 Count Name                      Group                                 

 ----- ----                      -----                                                                                                   
     2 a,b                       {@{value=System.Collections.Hashtable; label=a,b}, @{value=System.Collections.Hashtable; label=a,b}}    
     2 c,e                       {@{value=System.Collections.Hashtable; label=c,e}, @{value=System.Collections.Hashtable; label=c,e}}
```

You can then expand out each row to get the info you desire:

```
$a | %{ 
    new-object PsObject -prop @{"label" = "$($_[0]),$($_[1])"; value=@{ $_[2]=$_[3]}} 
} | 
group label | % {
    "[$(@($_.Name -split ",") + @($_.Group.value.values))]"
}
```

which gives:

```
[a b 10 20]
[c e 50 30]
```

To answer your second comment, no the above won;t guarantee the order. To guarantee it, you'll have to be explicit:

```
$a | %{ 
    new-object PsObject -prop @{"label" = "$($_[0]),$($_[1])"; value=@{ $_[2]=$_[3]}} 
} | 
group label | % {
    "[$(@($_.Name -split ",") + @($_.Group.value.x, $_.Group.value.y))]"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great solution. However, according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32640928/group-object-on-an-array/32641053#32641053, it's possible to use group directly on array. Can the solution be further simplified by it?

Comment: BTW, does `$_.Group.value.values` guarantees `x` being always in front of `y`? And what if the output need to in the order of [a b y x], [c e y x]?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 I think you can use a group scriptblock parameter, but I'm not sure the end result will be much simpler. See my edit in answer to your second comment.

Comment: Just found that `$_.Group.value.x` in the updated solution works on Windows 10 but not on Windows 7. It will get the error of `Property 'x' cannot be found on this object. Make sure that it exists.
At line:10 char:35
+     "[$(@($_.Name -split ",") + @($_.Group.value.x, $_.Group.value.y))]"
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict`

Comment: Yes that's a feature of powershell 3. Win7 comes with v2. You can install v4 on win7.

Comment: Is it possible to write it in Powershell 2? I may have no control of the powershell version on some of other computers. BTW, is Windows server 2008 R2 installed with Powershell V3+?

Comment: Actually my Windows 7 is already V3. So is it a V4 feature? `Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16398
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2`

Comment: I am pretty certain that it's a V3 feature. What it's doing is expanding an array ($_.Group) and selecting the value.x property of each element. You can unroll it yourself: `$($_.Group | %{$_.value.x})`