# Group-Object on an array?

Tags: powershell

How to use `Group-Object` on the first two columns (a, b) and (c, e) of the following array?

```
$a = @('a','b','x',10), 
@('a','b','y',20), 
@('c','e','x',50), 
@('c','e','y',30)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Group-Object` accepts anonymous calculated properties, in place of property names:

```
PS C:\> $a | Group-Object @{ Expression={$_[0]} },@{ Expression = {$_[1]} }
```

It also accepts a ScriptBlock:

```
PS C:\> $a | Group-Object {$_[0]},{$_[1]}
```

As long as the expression can be evaluated to a string:

```
PS C:\> Get-Help Group-Object -Parameter Property

-Property [<Object[]>]
    Specifies the properties for grouping. The objects are arranged into groups 
    based on the value of the specified property.

    The value of the Property parameter can be a new calculated property. 
    To create a calculated, property, create a hash table with an Expression key
    that specifies a string or script block value.
```

Comment: Just a note that anonymous is key here. If you supply a label with a hash it does nothing. ie @(1,2,3) | group-object @{l='mod';e={$_ % 2 -eq 0}}  does nothing but removing l='mod' will work.

Comment: @Fredrick What version of PowerShell are you using? In 5.1 and up, it's correctly validated and a `DictionaryKeyIllegal` error is thrown

Comment: @MathiasRJessen I see. I get the exception with 7.0.0-preview.4 but not  7.0.0-preview.2.

Comment: @Fredrick interesting. Might be a temporary regression in between, I haven't been keeping a close eye on changes to the utility cmdlets lately